# how show javascript confirm message after all input checkbox and radio groups checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

need show a confirm message after click at submit button, however, need show this window message only after my radio and checkbox is checked, how do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/G3LTe/

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group[1]" value="1">1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group[1]" value="2">2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group[1]" value="3">3
    </label>
        <br>
   <!-- 2 -->
     <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group[2]" value="1">1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group[2]" value="2">2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group[2]" value="3">3
    </label>
        <br>
 <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

JS

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var confirmacao = confirm("WARNING:\n go to next step? or cancel?");
    if(confirmacao == true) {
        console.log("OK");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("O envio foi cancelado");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a particular group of radio buttons has at least one radio button selected like this:

```
if ($(':radio[name="nameOfGroup"]:checked').length > 0)
{
    // at least one radio button with the name nameOfGroup is checked
}
```

So, go through each group, check if at least one radio button is selected for that group, and if so, proceed to the confirmation dialog:

```
var groups = {};
// get all of the unique radio button groups
$(':radio', form).each(function() {
    // object names are unique
    groups[this.name] = true;
});

var proceed = true;
$.each(groups, function(group, dummy) {
    if ($(':radio[name="' + group + '"]:checked').length == 0)
    {
        // none of the radio buttons of this group are checked, abort
        proceed = false;
        // break out of the .each() loop
        return false;
    }
});

if (!proceed)
{
    alert('Please check at least 1 radio button from each group!');
    return false;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2SL7/

(My code example could probably be somewhat simplified, but I wrote it out like that for clarity of what's going on.)

(Edited for arbitrary groups to address OP's concerns)

Comment: but i have several groups of radio in my form. with different group names, like this group[256]

Comment: $(':radio') is equivalent to $('*:radio') - it is more efficient to use $('input:radio') - see the docs http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

Comment: @pwdst What if you're scoping the search to the form? i.e. `$(':radio', form)`

Comment: Still less efficient that with an input prefix as jQuery will still need to look at every element in the form(s) regardless of type - simply inefficient within a narrower scope. Also, shouldn't form be quoted unless it is an existing JavaScript DOM element variable or jQuery object?

Comment: The resultant selector would probably look something like $('input:radio', $('form')) if I am reading the docs correctly. I'd generally write $('form').find('input:radio')

Comment: @pwdst Yes, although `form` is coming from a variable in my fiddle. I should have specified its intention. I agree with your notes on performance, albeit it's probably negligible at this level. Helpful to keep in mind nonetheless.